# UDP client-server. Client not sending string to the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, udp

I'm trying to split string if even or odd for example:

"Tea" will return two strings **string1** =  "Te" and **string2** = "a" - odd

"Coffee" will return two strings **string1** = "Cof" and **string2** = "fee"

I've got a working algorithm that does that.

Then client needs to send this to the server. My question how to send this to the server. How server accepts these two strings?

I'm newbie to python. Please help.

[image: Please find screenshot attached]

Server side:

```
import socket


def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000


    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Message From:  " +str(addr))
        print("From connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending: " + data)
        s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
    s.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client side:

```
      import socket

def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5001

    server = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    message = input('Please type a word ')
    while message != '':

        def splitWord(w):
            split = -((-len(w))//2)
            s1 = (w[:split])
            s2 = (w[split:])
            print(s1)
            print(s2)
            return


        a = splitWord(message)
        s.sendto(a.encode('utf-8'), server)

        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)  
        message = input('-> ')
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
            Main()
```

Comment: Can you post the output? What does the serve receive? Does the client get a response back?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to revisit your `splitWord()` function.

Inside `splitWord()` you create two substrings: s1 and s2, but don't do anything with them (other than printing). Your return is empty, and you don't modify the argument either.

A better way of to define this function is:

```
def splitWord(w):
  return w[:len(w)/2], w[len(w)/2:]
```

Example:

```
a = "Coffee"
f,s = splitWord(a)
print f, s

-> Cof fee
```

Also there is no reason to define `splitWord()` inside the while loop.

Comment: @AlinaKhachatrian your _splitWord()_ function is wrong.
I suggested a shorter, easier to understand, and correct _splitWord()_ function above.

Comment: message = input('Please type a word ')
    while message != '':

        def splitWord(w):
            return w[:len(w)/2], w[len(w)/2:]

        s1, s2 = splitWord(message)
        print(s1)
        print(s2) Gives me an error. TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method.